# Validating company registration numbers

Tags: validation, vba, excel

N.B. The next stage of this project, which covers parsing filenames and checking numbers against the list produced in this question, is covered [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/126095/parsing-3-million-filenames).

---

I have a list of company numbers (UK companies registered at Companies House) in an Excel spreadsheet. A CRN is an 8-character unique identifier attached to a specific registered corporation (usually 8-digits but not always).

Examples of company numbers:

- 02492078
- OC374102
- 03637689

This section of code handles:

- Retrieving the list of numbers
- Validating the numbers
- Adding any unique values to a `Dictionary` object

Later on, they will be used to check if a particular CRN is among the list I am targeting by using the `Dictionary.Exists()` method.

```
Option Explicit

Public Const COMPANY_NUMBER_COLUMN As Long = 1
Public Const parentFolderPath As String = "S:\Investments\Data\Companies House\Monthly Companies House Downloads\"

Public Sub ParseAllCompanyRecords()
    '/ Data Structure: "Company Numbers", once input, will be stored as strings
    '/ Company Number: 8-character string, generally 8-digits but sometimes with text prefixes E.G. "OC374102"

    '/ Folder Path for monthly CH downloads: "S:\Investments\Data\Companies House\Monthly Companies House Downloads\"
    '/ Filename Strucutre of a Monthly Folder: [parentFolderPath]"Accounts_Monthly_Data-"[Full Month Name][yyyy]"\" - Square Brackets not in filename
    '/ Filename Structure of an individual filing: [Monthly Folder Path]"Prod224_0005_"[8-character Company Registration Number]"_"[yyyymmdd][.html OR .xml] - Square Brackets not in filename

    Dim targetCompanyNumbers As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set targetCompanyNumbers = GetTargetCompanyNumbers

End Sub

Public Function GetTargetCompanyNumbers() As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim targetCompanyNumbers As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set targetCompanyNumbers = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim finalRow As Long, columnRange As Range
    With wsInputs
        finalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COMPANY_NUMBER_COLUMN).End(xlUp).row
        Set columnRange = .Range(.Cells(2, COMPANY_NUMBER_COLUMN), .Cells(finalRow, COMPANY_NUMBER_COLUMN))
    End With

    Dim columnArray As Variant
    columnArray = columnRange

    Dim LB1 As Long, UB1 As Long
    AssignArrayBounds columnArray, LB1, UB1

    Dim ix As Long
    Dim elementValue As Variant
    Dim companyNumber As String

    For ix = LB1 To UB1
        elementValue = columnArray(ix, 1)
        companyNumber = CompanyNumberFromValue(elementValue)
        If Not targetCompanyNumbers.Exists(companyNumber) Then targetCompanyNumbers.Add companyNumber, companyNumber
    Next ix

    Set GetTargetCompanyNumbers = targetCompanyNumbers 

End Function

Public Function CompanyNumberFromValue(ByVal vValue As Variant) As String
    '/ Company Number: 8-character string, generally 8-digits but sometimes with text prefixes E.G. "OC374102"

    Dim textValue As String, trimText As String
    Dim companyNumber As String

    textValue = CStr(vValue)
    trimText = Trim(textValue)

    If IsNumeric(trimText) Then
        companyNumber = Right("00000000" & trimText, 8) '/ Add back any leading zeroes that Excel may have stripped
    ElseIf Len(trimText) = 8 Then
        companyNumber = trimText
    Else
        '/ Not a number, not the correct number of digits. Invalid input.
        companyNumber = vbNullString
    End If

    CompanyNumberFromValue = companyNumber

End Function
```

Comment: "(usually 8-digits but not always)" What other options are in use? Everything from 6-digits up to 10?

Comment: I think he means it's always 8 characters, and usually those are 8 digits, but not always (e.g., provided `OC374102` for example)

Comment: `Set GetTargetCompanyNumbers = numbersDict` wouldn't compile with `Option Explicit`; shouldn't that be `Set GetTargetCompanyNumbers = targetCompanyNumbers`?

Comment: Ah yes. I renamed it and forgot to change the return statement. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> '/ Data Structure: "Company Numbers", once input, will be stored as strings
> '/ Company Number: 8-character string, generally 8-digits but sometimes with text prefixes E.G. "OC374102"
>
> '/ Folder Path for monthly CH downloads: "S:\Investments\Data\Companies House\Monthly Companies House Downloads\"
> '/ Filename Strucutre of a Monthly Folder: [parentFolderPath]"Accounts_Monthly_Data-"[Full Month Name][yyyy]"\" - Square Brackets not in filename
> '/ Filename Structure of an individual filing: [Monthly Folder Path]"Prod224_0005_"[8-character Company Registration Number]"_"[yyyymmdd][.html OR .xml] - Square Brackets not in filename
> ```

I don't see the need for the `/` slash here. The VBE renders comments in a very distinctive green color: really, you couldn't miss a comment block if you tried:

[image: ParseAllCompanyRecords() procedure comments without the slashes]

Why fully qualify `Scripting.Dictionary`, but not `Excel.Range`?

Seriously, your code isn't bad at all.

Except I'm not sure I understand the need for `AssignArrayBounds`, and `LB1`/`UB1` are awful names, as much as `ix` would be better off as either `i` or `index`.

---

This part can be simplified:

> ```
> If IsNumeric(trimText) Then
>     companyNumber = Right("00000000" & trimText, 8) '/ Add back any leading zeroes that Excel may have stripped
> ```

If `trimText` is numeric, then you can use the `Format` function to perform the padding:

```
If IsNumeric(trimText) Then
    companyNumber = Format(trimText, "00000000")
```

Simple as that!

I'd do away with multiple declarations in a single instruction:

> ```
> Dim textValue As String, trimText As String
> Dim companyNumber As String
>
> textValue = CStr(vValue)
> trimText = Trim(textValue)
> ```

...and move everything closer to their first usage:

```
Dim textValue As String
textValue = CStr(vValue)

Dim trimText As String
trimText = Trim$(textValue)

Dim result As String ' clearly the local I'm returning
```

Notice `Trim$` here. Under the hood, `Trim$` is really calling the `VBA.Strings._B_str_Trim` function; on the other hand, `Trim` is calling the `VBA.Strings._B_var_Trim` function. One returns a `String`, the other returns a `Variant`. By using the `Variant` variant, you're forcing an implicit conversion to a `String`, implicit conversion that can completely be avoided by calling the `String`-returning function in the first place.

The same applies to `Right`/`Right$`, respectively `VBA.Strings._B_var_Right` and `VBA.Strings._B_str_Right`. [Rubberduck's inspections wiki](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/wiki/Code-Inspections) will be updated for the 2.0 release with a full list of all these not-quite-string functions.

Comment: The comment slashes are just a habit I picked up somewhere. I rather like them.

Comment: Also, regards `LB1, UB1`, are they really that bad? When I'm handling an array, I'll often have LB/UB 1/2/3 as applicable and then `AssignArrayBounds` means I don't have to write out their assignments 6 times in a row.

Comment: `Scripting.Dictionary` is also just another habit I picked up somewhere along the way.

Comment: I've always wondered about the `$` functions, but I can't ever seem to find MS documentation.